# MacBook Pro heat issue

Tags: macbook-pro, fan, cooling, temperature

I have a MacBook Pro 13" (exactly [this one](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP645)) and seems to me that it's heating pretty much. The temperature is usually 80°C, and sometimes goes up to 90°C while just taking back-up and some internet browsing. I've used smcFanControl that uses the fans at max, but still, it seams that the temperature is too high for such a small work, especially after reading the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/136873/macbook-pro-15-with-i7-processor-any-problems-with-heat). Here is a screenshot from activity monitor with smcFanControl displaying the heat and the fans' RPM on the Menu Bar.

[image: Activity monitor screenshot]

So is this normal? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Do you smoke in the room that the laptop is in? I had a MacBook Pro that started to have heat issues. I was a heavy smoker in a small apartment. The smoke caked on the heatsinks and fans causing it to reduce in its cooling ability. I took apart the laptop and used Denatured Alcohol to clean the heatsinks. It worked perfectly afterwards.

Comment: No, I'm not a smoker and I'm using the computer on one of the coolest rooms of the apartment.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the internals?  Dust and other dirt can cause effective cooling to become ineffective.

Comment: Okay, first job I'll check it. Is there any special product that you'll recommend to clean with? like @kobaltz said that he used alcohol

Comment: I used Denatured Alcohol. On the heatsinks, you may need to find a long stiff bristle brush to get down in them. Also make sure that your fans are working. A dead fan could also cause rise in temps on a lappy.

Comment: At least one is working, I can hear it. Nead to check for the other to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid sitting the Mac on soft surfaces. The ideal position is on a hard surface, ideally slightly raised. If you cut a wine cork in half lengthways this makes a great raiser. The extra airflow underneath can make a big difference.

Conversely, placing a mac on a bed will allow it to build up heat.

if Safari is commonly using that much CPU you might want to look at investigating that: for example upgrading Flash if necessary.

To test whether it's likely to be dust as mentioned above, I suggest you restart the Mac and leave it running for a while with maybe something simple like a youtube video. Monitor the temperature and see whether heat is still a problem. If yes it might be the fan. If no, it might be software.